# Ball jumps when colliding with the edge of a rectangle

Tags: collision, 2d-games

this is my first bigger programming project, so I'm pretty much a beginner who came across a problem which bugs me for weeks now. Maybe someone can help. :)

I'm building a simple 2D-game. You can control a ball via pitching and yawing the smartphone. Whenever the ball hits the exact edge of an rectangle-obstacle-object, it first sinks into it and then jumps randomly out. It does not happen whenever the obstacles build a straight line.

After a while of debugging I'm pretty sure the error must lie somewhere in the physics part of the game. Here is the code:

```
        float var = gameView.screenSize()/2;
    // If the player touches the barrier, its speed will invert
    for(RectF r : barrier) {
        if(playerSpeedX > 0 && playerX > r.left - var && playerX < r.right + var && playerY >= r.top && playerY <= r.bottom) { playerX = r.left - var; playerSpeedX = -playerSpeedX;} // left
        if(playerSpeedX < 0 && playerX > r.left - var && playerX < r.right + var && playerY >= r.top && playerY <= r.bottom) { playerX = r.right + var; playerSpeedX = -playerSpeedX;} // right
        if(playerSpeedY > 0 && playerY > r.top - var && playerY < r.bottom + var && playerX >= r.left && playerX <= r.right) { playerY = r.top - var; playerSpeedY = -playerSpeedY;} // top
        if(playerSpeedY < 0 && playerY > r.top - var && playerY < r.bottom + var && playerX >= r.left && playerX <= r.right) { playerY = r.bottom + var; playerSpeedY = -playerSpeed;} //bottom
    }
```

var describes half of the size of an obstacle.

Maybe someone can help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: If the obstacle is *rectangular* what does the *single* value "*half of the size of an obstacle*" mean? A single dimension only makes sense for a *square* ( a rather specific rectangle).

Comment: Are you certain you did not mean "*half of the size of the ball*" which seems more likely given the code.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, the gamearea is divided in a 16:9 grid, so the ball and the obstacles take the same grid size. And yes, the obstacles are all squares, sorry.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about *all* the variables with respect to purpose and type, and I would suggest a more vertical layout of your code, with each sub-expression of the conditional and the conditional-body on a separate line each with a comment expressing what *you* think the expression does.  To be honest, the clarity of thought that will bring may allow you to determine the fault yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some assumptions in the absence if necessary information and laid out the code for better comprehensibility and debug capability.  This alone may help you resolve the problem yourself, but in any case is probably how toy should present the question if asking others to assist.  Only one conditional `if` block is shown for clarity, the others might follow the same pattern:

```
    // If the player touches the barrier, its speed will invert
    for(RectF r : barrier) 
    {
        if( playerSpeedX > 0 &&                  // If moving right and ...
            playerX > r.left - var &&            // ... ball edge past left of r and
            playerX < r.right + var &&           // ... ball edge not past right of r and   
            playerY >= r.top &&                  // ... ball centre below top of r and
            playerY <= r.bottom)                 // ... ball centre above top of r
        { 
            playerX = r.left - var;          // Move ball to the left
            playerSpeedX = -playerSpeedX;    // Change motion direction
        } 

        ...
    }
```

I am not certain these assumptions are correct, but suggest perhaps that the second and third boolean sub-expressions in the conditional might be changed from `>` to `>=`, the that the `\\Move ball to the left` statement is then unnecessary.

An advantage of laying out the code this way apart from clarity and the ability to clearly comment the purpose of each sub-expression is that when stepping the code in a line-oriented source-level debugger, you can verify the behaviour each sub-expression and statement individually rather then having everything happen at once and have no idea why (or at least being less obvious why).  Using a [debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) is likley in any case to be a far more efficient method of fixing development problems such as this that posting questions on SO.